# Python 2.7 regex statement to add acute accent to the first matching character

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to use Python regex to add an acute accent to the first matching character of a two character pattern.  For instance I'd like `oä́` to become `óä́`.  Below is the regex code I'm using.

```
raw = oä́gtra’

raw = re.sub(ur"([ieäaouëö])([í|é|ä́|á|ó|ú|ö́|ë́])", ur"\1́\2", raw) # notice the acute accent between \1 and \2
```

To help troubleshoot this I'm using the following statement.

```
if re.match(ur"([ieäaouëö])([í|é|ä́|á|ó|ú|ö́|ë́])", raw) is not None:
    print "it found the pattern..."
```

The statement 'it found the pattern...' is printed so it seems my regex statement is correctly identifying the pattern I just need help getting the acute accent added to the first matching character.

Below is the other code that I have also tried.  But this code doesn't seem to work either.

```
print repr(raw) # prints u'o\xe4\u0301gtra\u2019'
mapping = {"i":"í","e":"é","ä":"ä́","a":"á","o":"ó","u":"ú","ö":"ö́","ë":"ë́"}
pattern = "([ieäaouëö])([í|é|ä́|á|ó|ú|ö́|ë́])"
replacement = lambda match: mapping[match.group(1)] + match.group(2)
raw = re.sub(pattern, replacement, raw)
```

Thanks for all answered offered and any help in the future!  It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `is not None` is redundant in this case, if a match exists, it will evaluate to True automatically when used as a boolean.

Comment: The answer depends on how you represent the accents: composed or decomposed. For example, `í` can be `\xed` or `i\u0301`. What does `repr(raw)` return?

Comment: If you have non-ascii strings in Python 2 source code, be sure to [specify the encoding](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing some magic with `ord` and `chr` and encodings, but i think you're best off hardcoding a mapping.

```
mapping = {"i":"í","e":"é","ä":"ä","a":"á","o":"ó","u":"ú","ö":"ö","ë":"ë"}
pattern = "([aeiou])([aeiou])"
replacement = lambda match: mapping[match.group(1)] + match.group(2)
text = re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)
```

Do note that it's imcomplete, you need to expand the dictionary and the regex pattern

Comment: thanks for the help I tried what I thought was expanding the dictionary and regex pattern and I still can't seem to get it to work.